# Cannot start SQL Server Agent service

Tags: sql-server

Both the SQL Server and SQL Server Browser services are running without a problem on manual but the SQL Server Agent does not start because of the error shown in the screenshot [The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ID76.png).

So I check sqlagent logs and found this

> 2017-05-13 10:19:19 - ? [100] Microsoft SQLServerAgent version 11.0.6248.0 (X64 unicode retail build) : Process ID 2380
>
> 2017-05-13 10:19:19 - ? [495] The SQL Server Agent startup service account is
>
> 2017-05-13 10:19:19 - ? [393] Waiting for SQL Server to recover database 'msdb'...
>
> 2017-05-13 10:19:19 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
>
> 2017-05-13 10:19:19 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
>
> 2017-05-13 10:19:19 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 229, The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (DisableAgentXPs)
>
> 2017-05-13 10:19:19 - ! [000] The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_sqlagent_update_agent_xps', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 229)
>
> 2017-05-13 10:19:19 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)

Is this because the server agent does not have sysadmin privileges or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, you're using an Express version of SQL. SQLAgent is not supported by SQLExpress.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7d09c64c-2fcd-482c-aace-fa5f1fc52f45/sql-server-express-2014-and-sql-server-agent?forum=sqlexpress